# file_put_contents('items.json',json_encode($item));

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

How to create a json file in laravel to store data in json format so that I can use it in ajax coz I'm having problem in autocomplete search. I have done this but it worked in Category not in item.

```
$catagories=Catagory::where('status',1)->get(['name'])->toArray();
    $items=Item::where('status',1)->get()->toArray();
    $cats=array();   
    $item=array();
    foreach($catagories as $cat){
        array_push($cats,$cat['name'])
    }
    file_put_contents('category.json',json_encode($cats));
    file_put_contents('items.json',json_encode($item));
```

Comment: The json does not have to be in a file to be ajaxable?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$item` is never used, so it won't print anything on the file. You need to use the `$items` variable

Try

```
file_put_contents('items.json',json_encode($items));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because your item array is empty

```
        $catagories=Catagory::where('status',1)->get(['name'])->toArray();
        $items=Item::where('status',1)->get()->toArray();
        $cats=array();   
        $item=array();
        foreach($catagories as $cat){
            array_push($cats,$cat['name'])
        }
        file_put_contents('category.json',json_encode($cats));
        file_put_contents('items.json',json_encode($item));
```

You are using $item array on last line which is empty, coz you didn't fill it from $items array